# Find the optimal value of a LP given part information about parameter matrix

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider a LP

$$\min_{x, y} c^Tx + d^T y$$
$$s.t. Ax + By \geq b$$
$$x, y \geq 0,$$

where $A$ is a square matrix such that $A\geq I$ componentwise.

Suppose that this LP is feasible. What is the minimum value of the objective function.

---

If at least one element of $c$ is negative, then the minimum value is $-\infty$.
If $c \geq 0$ componentwise, some elements of $d$ are negative and $\exists \hat{y} \geq 0$, $y_i = \infty$, $d_i < 0$ and $Ax + B\hat{y} \geq b$, then  the minimum value is $-\infty$.

If $c \geq 0$ componentwise and the problem is bounded, then the KKT conditions of this problem are:
$$c - A^T\lambda - \mu_1 = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$d - B^T\lambda - \mu_2 = 0 \tag{2}$$
$$\lambda^T(b - Ax - By) = 0 \tag{3}$$
$$\mu_1 x = 0 \tag{4}$$
$$\mu_2 y = 0 \tag{5}$$
$$Ax + By \geq b \tag{6}$$
$$x, y, \lambda, \mu_1, \mu_2 \geq 0 \tag{7}$$

But I still cannot solve the problem or just find the optimal value since I have no idea about matrix $B$ and $A$.

Also I am not sure how to find all of conditions such that this problem is unbounded.